# ACF Tag It Field and createTag

Tags: jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, tag-it

I’m using the [Tag it Field add on](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-tag-it/) for ACF and just want to do the simplest thing of adding a tag with jQuery. As there’s no documentation for this I’m trying to use the [original jQuery plugin documentation](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) and the methods explained there in conjunction with the wordpress ACF [acf.add_action('load') hook](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-custom-javascript-fields/).

I’m trying something like this in the wordpress theme's functions.php ( where rhymes is the tagit field’s wrapper id ) :

```
function my_acf_input_admin_footer()
{
    ?>  
    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function($){
        acf.add_action( 'load', function( $el ){

            $( '#rhymes ul.tagit' ).tagit(  'createTag', 'example tag'  );
        });

    })(jQuery);

    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'acf/input/admin_footer', 'my_acf_input_admin_footer' );
```

It's just not doing anything, has anyone got any experience using the tagit jQuery UI plugin and/or the wordpress ACF add on implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly selector mistake on my behalf. The Tag It ACF plugin applies the tagit jquery to an input and not a ul. In my case I was able to access the element and call tagit functionality like this:

```
$( '#rhymes input.acf-tag-it', $el ).tagit( 'createTag', 'new tag' );
```